# WPF увеличить texblock при наведении

Tags: wpf, wpf-grid

Есть следующая разметка в wpf:

```
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1.0*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на TextBlock находящийся в строке 6(со слиянием двух колонок) занял всю красную область(Row=1,Column=0,ColumnSpan=2 RowSpan=7 - т.е. Остался только он). А при наведении на нулевую строку, всё вернулось обратно.
[image: Разметка]

Comment: Trigger использовать для элемента, и там выставлять параметры паренту, это у вас грид.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1.0*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="6"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="7"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если другие контролы будут показываться поверх вашего `TextBlock` — установите ему `Panel.ZIndex` побольше.

Comment: Ничего не понимаю, у вас вижу, что всё работает. Но у меня мало того, что ZIndex 10000 не помогает стереть, так ещё и роу не меняется, (т.е. только последние 3 строки использует)

Comment: За наводку большое спасибо, сейчас буду пытаться понять что не так.

Comment: проблема была в том, что с texblock не убрал свойство Grid.Row=6

Comment: Обратите внимание, `Grid.Row` устанавливается сеттером в стиле, если вы будете указывать его непосредственно в разметке, триггер не сможет его переопределить, т.к. будет иметь меньший приоритет